# font-size de un archivo css no reconocido en host

Tags: css, html5

Estoy trabajando en una web que he probado a subir al host.
En VS code con live server se ve correctamente, también con default browser y en dferentes pantallas con distintas resoluciones.

El problema viene al subirla al host. En este momento, al abrir la pagina con el mismo html y css la fuente se descuadra. Intento modificar el css pero es como si no detectara la propiedad font-size. La diferencia se ve en las siguientes imagenes. No consigo adaptarlo bien 100% y no se a que se debe esta diferencia.

[image: no desbordado y reactiva a font-size]

[image: no reactiva a font-size]

```css
 #anclas{
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 30px;
    width: 40%;
    height:auto;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(46, 79, 229, 0.981) 0%,
      rgb(61, 163, 231) 47%,
      rgb(141, 205, 239) 100%
    );;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 4px 0px 8px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    transition: 1s;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  #anclas a{
    
    margin-top: 20px;
    color:white ;
    text-decoration: overline;
    font-size: 1em;
    
  }
  #anclas a:hover{
    color: #ddec5a;
  }
  #anclas ul{
    list-style: none;
  }
  #principal{
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(249, 253, 254);
    font-size: 2em;
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white,
                 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
                 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
                 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
                 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }
  #principal p{
    color: rgb(249, 253, 254);
    font-size: 1em;
    font-family: "sans-serif";
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 white,
                 0 2px 0 #c9c9c9,
                 0 6px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.1),
                 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.3),
                 0 3px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.25),
                 0 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2),
                 0 20px 20px rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  }

  #presentacion{
   position: relative;
   border-radius: 10px;
   margin-top: 9px;
   margin-left: 50px;
   width: 50%;
   height: 60vh;
   background:linear-gradient(90deg,
   rgba(238, 28, 28, 0.821) 0%,
   rgb(197, 59, 59) 47%,
   rgba(42, 119, 226, 0.8) 100%)
   
  }
  #presentacion::before, #presentacion::after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 10px;
    left: -8px;
    top: -8px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,
    rgba(238, 28, 28, 0.821) 0%,
    rgb(197, 59, 59) 47%,
    rgba(42, 119, 226, 0.8) 100%);
    background-size: 300%;
    width: calc(100% + 16px);
    height: calc(100% + 16px);
    z-index: -1;
    animation: gradiente 5s ease infinite;
  }
  @keyframes gradiente{
    0%{
      background-position: 0% 200%;
    }
    50%{
      background-position: 200% 0%;
    }
    100%{
      background-position: 0% 330%;
    }
  }
  #secciontienda{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    #anclas{
      padding: 10px;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: 17px;
      width:100% ;
      height: auto;
    }
    #presentacion{
      display: none;
      
    }
   
}
```

```html
<section id="secciontienda">
    <nav id="anclas">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="libros.html">Libros</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="ebooks.html">eBooks</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="tablets.html">Tablets</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="Pijamas.html">Pijamas</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="Anclajes.html">Anclajes</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="Apositos.html">Apósitos</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="Gorros.html">Gorros sanitarios</a></li><br>
        <li><a href="UtilesEnf.html">Útiles de Enfermería</a></li><br>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <section id="presentacion">
      <article class="parrafos" id="principal">
        <p><i>En esta sección encontraras todo aquello
            que podría hacer tu vida mas fácil durante la diálisis.
            Tanto si eres Enfermera, como si eres paciente.
          </i>
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>
  </section>
```

Comment: Fijate si la sintaxis de tu CSS es correcta, por las dudas: ya con un rápido vistazo vi un `;;` en una propiedad, por ejemplo.

Comment: revisa las rutas, verifica la consola para ver si tus fuentes o archivos css dan un 404

Comment: @jefferzon Bol no da ningún 404 ni nada. Me doy cuenta de que dependiendo del monitor, si funciona correctamente. Tengo la   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: @padaleiana Ahora resulta que elimino toda la carpeta de css y continua la web con estilo. Es como si la ruta de enlace del stylesheet estuviese cogiendo otra en vez de la ruta del hosting. <link rel="stylesheet" href="recursos/tienda.css" />. Tal vez es esto lo que está mal? Porque si borro la hoja de estilos la pagina sigue con estilo.

Comment: El clásico: _¿borraste la caché del navegador?_

Comment: @padaleiana Correcto. Todo el día peleando con esto y resulta que es un clásico. Voy a llorar.

Comment: Tranquilo. Ya sabés para la próxima :)